# jquery cookie set throwing unexpected string error

Tags: jquery, cookies

Im using the jquery cookie plugin and getting an `unexpected string error` when attempting to set it.

```
jQuery('#select').change(function() {
    if(jQuery(this).val() == "defaultselect"){
        jQuery.cookie('mycookie':'123456789'); // This line throws the error
    }
    return false;   
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a syntax error `:` should be `,`

```
jQuery('#select').change(function() {
    if(jQuery(this).val() == "defaultselect"){
        jQuery.cookie('mycookie','123456789'); //`:` should be `,`
    }
    return false;   
});
```